# Cycles in a highly connected directed graph - networkx

Tags: python, graph-theory, networkx

I have a moderately sized directed graph consisting of around 3000 nodes and 260000 edges that i have built in `networkx`. The network is mostly transitive: i.e if a is directed to b, and b is directed to c then a directs to c. I am trying to use `simple_cycles algorithm` from `networkx` package to obtain a list of every cycle in that network (i.e any violation of transitivity).

To do this i run

```
l = nx.simple_cycles(G)
cycle_list = list(l)
```

where G is the network.

I am running to the issue where the second line cannot run to completion (i've left it running for 24hr). When i apply the algorithm to a subset of 2100 node of the original network it takes around 4 seconds to run.

Any idea where the bottleneck is and what I can do to fix it so it runs quickly.

Update: Creation method

```
df = pd.read_csv('epsilon_djordje.csv')
edges =  [tuple([df['i'][x],df['j'][x]]) if df['f.i.j'][x] > 0    else tuple([df['j'][x],df['i'][x]]) if df['f.i.j'][x] < 0 else     tuple([0,0]) for x in range(0,len(df))]
edges = list(set(edges))
edges.remove(tuple([0,0]))
G = nx.DiGraph(edges)
```

As a reference:

df['i'] is a column of strings (which correspond to the nodes).
df['j'] is a column of strings ( which correspond to the nodes).
df['f.i.j'] is a column of floats (which determine the direction of the edges between two nodes).

Comment: How many edges were with your 2100 nodes cycle? How do you create your graph? [This paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0204007) which is the algorithm used by `nx.simple_cycles` seem to indicate that it shouldn't be that costly, which would point toward an issue somewhere else in your code

Comment: The subgraph has around 12000 edges. I generated the graph by creating a list of tuples called edges where each tuple contains two strings (first string indicating first node, second string indicating second node and then using

    G = nx.DiGraph(edges)

Comment: It would be nice if you are able to include the creation method of the directed graph, so that we can reproduce the same steps as you did. Otherwise I'll try on my side, and see if I get to the same issue. (You can use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45594251/edit) button to add your code)

Comment: Ok. I've added the creation method, with some detail of what kind of data i use. (hope it's clear).